# Take as input str, a string. Write a code which moves all ‘x’ from the string to its end.Print the value returned

Tags: c++

For following input( abexexex) it is showing error:

```
   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::erase: __pos (which is 7) > this->size() (which is 4)
```

source code:

```
#include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

  int main()

  {   
      string str ;
      getline(cin,str);
      int s=str.size();

       int i=0;
       int count=0;
        while(i<s)
        {
          if(str[i]=='x')
            {
              count++;
            str.erase(i,i); 
            }
          i++;

        }
          while(count!=0)
        {
            str=str+'x';
            count--;
        }
            cout<<str;

        }
```

Comment: Side note: There should be no need for `s`. In modern C++ [`std::string::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) is guaranteed to be constant time complexity and while this could be accomplished with a constant time of 9.8 billion years, I have a hard time picturing any implementation more complicated than a quick bit of pointer math or returning a built-in cached length. Even before C++11 I know of no major implementations that had a non-constant `size`. `while (i < str.size())` would have been just as fast and eliminated the bug.

Answer (score 3):

@HakanBatmaz provided explanation of the problem. Here is proper way to do it:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

int main() {   
    std::string str ;
    std::getline(std::cin,str);

    auto it = std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), 'x');
    std::fill(it, str.end(), 'x');

    std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

Comment: read question title it describes desired behavior. Removed `x` should reappear at the end of string.

Comment: I think @0x499602D2 's point may be that `std::remove` works by moving all of the elements to be removed to the end of the container. The `fill`'s not needed because the last elements in `str` will be the "removed" 'x's.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah but then I ran it without the fill and it didn't work. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7ffa294714e8368 It seems it is needed.

Comment: Just [reread the cppref  page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and yup. *Removing is done by shifting (by means of move assignment) the elements in the range in such a way that the elements that are not to be removed appear in the beginning of the range.* Moves the keep stuff to the beginning, not the discard stuff to the end. Doesn't have to move the remove stuff at all. Wonder where I got that idea from.

Answer (score 2):

I think `str.erase(i,i);` is responsible for the exception. after erasing some chars from string the size s should be updated or you should implement it some way around.

Comment: I wonder who vote you down and why? After all you are correct what is the problem.

Comment: maybe they are expecting something else